# SQL Server 2012 Login Failure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, logins

As of this morning we have had thousands of failed login attempts to our SQL Server 2012 box.

Error :

> Login failed for user 'Domain\User'. Reason: Infrastructure error occurred.
>   Check for previous errors. [CLIENT: 10.xxx.xxx.xxx]
>
> Error: 18456
>   Severity: 14
>   State: 1

I have checked all the logs, permissions, and scoured forums for help on this issue but to no avail.

> Server Login & Database User accounts are enabled
>   Server Login is mapped to the database that it has access too
>   Windows & SQL Server Authentication is applied
>   SA account is enabled
>   No orphaned users
>   etc etc...

Any ideas ?

Comment: Are there any other errors in the error log, such as SSPI errors? I appreciate that with thousands of errors, there's a lot to look through.

Comment: there are not unfortunately. All just "Login Failed" and "Error: 18456". this is why im having such an issue

Comment: Look at aaron's blog. https://sqlblog.org/2020/07/28/troubleshooting-error-18456 Maybe it can help you. Or you can trace with `user errors` to see what's going on.

Comment: Unlike the error message that is returned to you, if you look at the error log you will see that specific State numbers will describe your problem.  So, do look at Aaron's blog post.

Answer (score 1):

The box lost connection to the domain controller, hence the login issues

Answer (score 0):

As per MSDN BOL http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/02/21/536201.aspx The message is kept fairly nondescript to prevent information disclosure to unauthenticated clients.   In particular, the 'State' will always be shown to be '1' regardless of the nature of the problem.  To determine the true reason for the failure, the administrator can look in the server's error log where a corresponding entry will be written.

If the server encounters an error that prevents a login from succeeding, the client will display the following error mesage.

```
Msg 18456, Level 14, State 1, Server <server name>, Line 1
Login failed for user '<user name>'
```